# Rotating and scaling a displacement map to fit trapezoidal shaped plane

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement

I have successfully uploaded a displacement map I created in PixPlant3 to Blender. The texture I made aligns to the dimensions of a trapezoidal plane that I made, as my goal was for one instance of this texture to fill the plane. However, when I upload the texture, it appears rotated and out of scale with the plane. When I view this in UV mode, nothing shows up aside from the png view of the texture itself. **How can I rotate and scale this texture to fit the dimensions of my plane?**

[image: my view]

[image: approximately what the texture should look like on the plane when applied properly]

[image: approximately what the texture should look like on the plane when applied properly]

Comment: Whole thing of fit this is in the UV layout. Go to edit mode when in UV layout and select all polygons on object the UVs should be visible now. If you cant see UVs may be there are non and you have to unwrap the object. Also, UVs vork best on square image. There is a lot to check. If possible, upload your project.